# How do I specify an interaction in h2o.glm?

Tags: r, glm, h2o, interaction

**Background:**
In R, using a linear model, I could write a formula

```
est <- lm(Y~1+A+B+C+D:A+E:D+E:F+B:A+B:D+C:A+C:D+C:B, data=mydata)
```

If "Y" happens to be binomial, then I can also write:

```
est <- glm(Y~1+A+B+C+D:A+E:D+E:F+B:A+B:D+C:A+C:D+C:B, data=mydata, family = binomial)
```

But... 
When I go to h2o.glm, I have to use the "x=.., y=.." form.

```
my_glm.hex <- h2o.glm(y=y_idx,x=x_idx,
                  training_frame = "my_train",
                  validation_frame = "my_valid",
                  model_id = "my_glm.hex",
                  family = "binomial",
                  lambda_search = TRUE,
                  balance_classes = TRUE)
```

**Question:**
How do I add a formula that allows me to fit a generalized linear model (glm) with interactions using h2o.glm?

Addendum:
I'm not sure what tags outside of 'r', 'h2o', and 'fitting' should be used here.  If you think of something relevant, could you suggest it in comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For h2o.glm, all you need to add is an `interactions` parameter, which takes the form a list of attributes in `x` whose interactions you want to include. In your case, it might look like:

```
# supposing x contains variables A, B, C, etc.
interacting_variables <- c('B', 'D', 'E', 'F')

my_glm.hex <- h2o.glm(y=y_idx,x=x_idx,
                      training_frame = "my_train",
                      validation_frame = "my_valid",
                      model_id = "my_glm.hex",
                      family = "binomial",
                      lambda_search = TRUE,
                      balance_classes = TRUE,
                      interactions = interacting_variables)
```

For a list like the one above, all pairwise combinations of the four variables will be computed.

You can find more on the [h2o site](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/interactions.html).

Comment: Does automl take interactions?